# How to use for loop to create new data frames using i in the name of data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I'm relatively new to R and have been searching this forum for an example.  While I have found some similar questions and answers, I still can't seem to get my code to work.

I would like to use a for loop in R to create a series of new data frames that incorporates the temporary value for i in the name of the new data frame.  I have the following code in which I would like to create two new data frames: metrics_2013, and metrics_2014.  I have some calculations (mutate and filter) to apply to the new dataframes, but I'm leaving that out for simplicity.

```
yearlist <- as.list(c(2013, 2014))
metrics_ <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 0))
for (i in yearlist) {
  
  maxyear <- i
  minyear <- maxyear - 7
  
metrics_[as.character(i)] <- mutatedata %>% 
  group_by(symbol) %>% 
  filter(year>=minyear & year<=maxyear) %>% 
  summarize(
    avgroepercent = mean(roe,na.rm = TRUE), 
    avgrocpercent = mean(roc, na.rm = TRUE),
    epsroc = (((last(eps))/(first(eps)))^(1/(maxyear-minyear))-1)
    )
}
```

In this case both dataframes (for 2013 and 2014) will be equal to "data", as all I'm having trouble with at the moment is creating data frames with names based on the value of i.  I believe that it may have something to do with [], vs [[]], or maybe I need to define metrics_[i] prior to the for loop???  But any assistance is much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
library(dplyr)
yearlist <- c(2013, 2014)

lapply(yearlist, function(x) {
  maxyear <- x
  minyear <- maxyear - 7
  
  mutatedata %>% 
    filter(year>=minyear & year<=maxyear) %>% 
    group_by(symbol) %>% 
    summarize(
      avgroepercent = mean(roe,na.rm = TRUE), 
      avgrocpercent = mean(roc, na.rm = TRUE),
      epsroc = (((last(eps))/(first(eps)))^(1/(maxyear-minyear))-1)
    )
}) -> data
```

where `data` is a list of dataframes. If you want to create separate dataframes you can use `list2env`.

```
names(data) <- paste0('metrics_', yearlist)
list2env(data, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Using lapply worked perfectly.  Thanks so much @Ronak Shah . A second question has arisen.  Now I'd like to do a left_join or merge to add a column of information from a 2nd dataframe.  Let's call that new dataframe: Industry.  I'd simply like to add a column that pulls the industry data from this dataframe and add it to each new dataframe that was created above.  I've tried doing a simple loop like below: for (i in yearlist) {calcmetrics_[[i]] <- left_join(calcmetrics_[[i]], Industry)} . But there appears to be an error in reading, or using, calcmetrics_[[i]] within the left_join command.

Comment: I was able to answer my own question.  I used the map function and it worked to utilize left_join on the list I created using lapply above.  map(data, ~data.frame(.) %>% then left_join.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this slightly differently will be a lot simpler *and* make your life easier in the long run. Instead of having several variables with auto-generated names, have a list whose elements have auto-generated names. e.g.:

```
data <- data.frame(a=1:2)

metrics <- list()
for (i in yearlist) {
  metrics[as.character(i)] <- data
}
```

(there may be a better way to do this than with a loop, but that's another topic)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response MattB!  Yeah, I understand that a loop may not be the best option.  But I'm trying to take baby steps in learning R:)  I tried running your code and I get this error "Error in metrics[as.character(i)] <- data : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'list'"

Comment: Have you assigned something to the `data` variable? :-)

Comment: Yeah, it's a data frame that I'm going to use to perform a series of calculations on, but I wanted to create the data frames first.......  So to answer your question, yes.  But it may not be what you intended on it being in your set of code???

Comment: FYI - what I had intended on doing with this code is to use: group_by, filter, and summarize to perform a series of calculations on the "data" dataframe.  And these new dataframes with 2013 and 2014 in the name define a subset of information to be used in the summarize function.

Comment: See my edit. If you've assigned something to `data` then you shouldn't be getting that error.

Comment: Ok, great.  I got that to work.  Thanks so much.  But.....and sorry for being ignorant....so now I have a list that contains 2013 and 2014.  I need to create a large dataframe (or series of dataframes that has 2013 and 2014 as part of the name) that will contain the results of a series of custom functions that are inside a summarize() function.  Sorry, but I guess I don't see how this will help.  I'll add my full set of code with a few of my custom functions and maybe that will help.  Stay tuned.

Comment: I've updated the code in the original question.  FYI - mutatedata is a large data frame with financial data for many companies that is organized by symbol and year.